# Java/DB2 FETCH FIRST :n ROWS with custom parameter

Tags: java, sql, db2, fetch, spring-jdbc

So this is what we're looking at, I want to be able to pass in a parameter into my fetch clause so that I can have a query with a custom FETCH amount.

From what i have read in other SOs, this, sadly, is not available via DB2 database. However, the answers I've seen haven't been very good so I am asking the question for my specific situation.

Other options I have tried that DO work:

- Concatenating my String statements to create my custom query.
- Instead of using a FETCH, use a WHERE col_1 BETWEEN value1 AND value2
- As commented by @bhamby, you can also replace a BETWEEN stmt by using > and < within a WHERE clause

To give you a basic example of what I am looking for (I'm using Spring JDBC with named parameters btw)

```
private static final String SQL_FETCH_NEXT = ""
    + "SELECT * " 
    + "FROM ( SELECT "
    + "     (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID, AGE)) AS RUNNING_NO, ID, NAME, AGE "
    + "         FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1 PERSON "
    + "     ) AS TABLE_ONE "
    + "WHERE TABLE_ONE.RUNNING_NO > :rowNumber "
    + "ORDER BY TABLE_ONE.RUNNING_NO "
    + "FETCH FIRST :fetchCount ROWS ONLY ";
```

And so, per my query above (which doesn't work due to the :fetchCount) how can I get a custom param (or an descent substitute) for the FETCH amount?

Comment: Actually, `BETWEEN` equates to `>=`/`<=`, which is part of what causes problems with certain types (your version would have the same problem, just at the other end of the range).  Due to [Dijkstra's arguments about range querying](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html), I recommend starting with an inclusive lower-bound (that is, `>=`), though I'd say stick with the results of `ROW_NUMBER()`, even though it starts at 1 - you're querying for the _range_, not the actual indices.  This has the benefit of still working if you switch to a non-integer range, too.

Comment: Thanks for the information and for the article, I had not read that before. My friend directed me to this post which I also found very informative, [Pagination](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0307balani/0307balani.html)

Comment: ...That post has at least one major problem with it: "If the order is not a factor .. then we can eliminate the ORDER BY..." - If you want your search results to be _stable_, `ORDER BY` is required, **period**.  Otherwise there's a risk that the order will change unexpectedly (likelihood varies, but this is a risk).  If the order isn't a factor, use the primary key (rows in order and _stored_ in that order).  Otherwise, use whatever criteria is appropriate (and customers don't care about primary keys).  And `ROW_NEXT` is clearly just a column alias, I don't know why it's called a "feature"...

Answer (score 3):

You pretty much already have all the pieces you need, since you're already using `ROW_NUMBER()`.  Why don't you try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID, AGE) AS RUNNING_NO
        ,ID
        ,NAME
        ,AGE
    FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1 PERSON
) AS TABLE_ONE
WHERE TABLE_ONE.RUNNING_NO  > :rowNumber
  AND TABLE_ONE.RUNNING_NO <= :rowNumber + :fetchCount
ORDER BY TABLE_ONE.RUNNING_NO
```

Comment: It is another option, but you are essentially just replacing the BETWEEN stmt by duplicating the RUNNING_NO. I wonder if there are dramatic differences in performance. I will add it as an option above and run some tests.

Comment: Even though it's something you already tried, this is a good option.  You don't really need to fetch first N rows.  Using a between, or this option would be just as good as fetch first N rows. I don't think there would be any observable performance difference between this and "FETCH FIRST N ROWS ONLY" since you're already doing the work to generate the ROW_NUMBER().  That's where all the overhead is going to be.

Answer (score 2):

The Row_Number() function is one of the best options to use, but the FETCH FIRST N ROWS syntax is not necessary when using it since you already are doing most of the work to generate the row_number(), so you can just use it to filter down to the rows you want using the row_number value.

Aside from that option, I think the first option you listed that you already tried is the best alternative (concatenating the number into the query string). Assuming you have proper indexing.  (without indexing, the row_number option is always better).

So IF you can get the correct index on the table:

Since you're working in Java, you could still avoid SQL injection and build your query dynamically by appending an integer into the query into the "Fetch first N rows only".

The one downside to that strategy is that the dynamic statement cache will have to cache one version of the code per page, and you'll have extra DAO code to spin to the right starting point (page - 1 * items per page).

As long as you are using a numeric data type, SQL injection should not be possible:

```
private static final String SQL_FETCH_NEXT = ""
    + " SELECT ID, NAME, AGE "
    + " FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1 PERSON "
    + " ORDER BY ID, AGE ";

private static Object runQuery(int pageNum, String filterText) {

//boilerplate code skipped

String sql = SQL_FETCH_NEXT + " fetch first " + pageNum * VALUES_PER_PAGE + " rows only ";

//the rest of the method

}
```

In this case the FETCH FIRST N ROWS syntax would be warranted for one reason:  Sort avoidance, and avoiding a materialization of the results. The sort will likely be the biggest cost to your original query, and using ROW_NUMBER will force you to materialize the whole result set to sort and assign row numbers. Avoiding the sort would require an index on ID, and AGE (in the same order as your order by statement).  Or if you have filters, you'd have to have them first on the index, and then your ordering columns.

The reason this would work is that the database engine would use the index to bring the data back in the order requested, and it would not have to do a sort.

the downside to this strategy is that you are bringing back extra data when you get past the first page (because you're getting pageNumber * itemsPerPage rows).  So to determine the best course of action, you'd have to evaluate whether it's common to have your users page past the first two or three pages.

Even then, it's hard to say when the amount of extra data you're pulling back is too much. You'd have to run some test to check which query is faster: the one with the sort (ROW_NUMBER) or the one pulling back (pageNumber-1)*itemsPerPage too many rows.

I should note:  you could avoid the sort in the ROW_NUMBER strategy as well.  So materialization is the main concern with that.

I would guess that with a decent amount of data in the table, it's better to avoid the materialization (since you're operating on ALL of the data in the result set to sort and materialize it inside of the query).  With a small amount of data, it would be better to do the sort, and not pull back the extra rows across the network.

However, if your users almost NEVER page, then the sort avoidance option is the best, for obvious reason.

So between the two strategies it comes down to two trade-offs:

1. Materialize the result set in the database engine to assign row numbers before limiting it to a subset.  But only pulling exactly what you want back into Java.
2. Quickest performance for the first page, but pulling back (pageNumber-1)*itemsPerPage more data across the network than required to get down to the subset you want for subsequent pages.(and a bit of spinning in java).